# EditText - How to detect typing 3 or more characters and perform search

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search

Need help. Already 4 days nothing happens.
Trying to do a SQLite database search.
How to make it so that the listview is not displayed immediately, but only when the user enters a search query?
That is, the data from the database was not filtered, but matches appeared in the listview when the user enters a request.
I am very grateful to everyone in advance!`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    userFilter = findViewById(R.id.userFilter);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final DatabaseAccessSmeta databaseAccessSmeta = DatabaseAccessSmeta.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccessSmeta.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccessSmeta.Search();
    databaseAccessSmeta.close();


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.region_list, quotes);
    this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.getFilter().filter(userFilter.getText().toString());

    userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });


}`
```

Comment: So, what you want is: After user press enter key, the search will load, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load result only after user presses enter/search key, then no need to add `TextWatcher`, just add EditorActionListener:

```
/* Adding action listener for handling search click */
userFilter.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
        // Hiding keyboard
        userFilter.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (in != null) {
            in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userFilter.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        // Initiate search
        adapter.getFilter().filter(userFilter.getText().toString());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Also in your xml, add `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` to your `EditText`.

**Edit:**

If you want it to be visible after typing 3 characters, then you have to add `TextWatcher`:

```
userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String query = (s != null) ? s.toString() : "";
        if (query.length() >= 3) {
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        } else {
            // Either set an empty list or change visibility
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adapter.getFilter().filter("");
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How to make a live search? So that the options appear in the listview in real time? The problem is that the list is displayed immediately, and after input is filtered. I need the list to be invisible and appear after entering 3 letters.

Comment: For that functionality, you can add a TextWatcher, and inside its `afterTextChanged()` check if its length >= 3 and based on it, you can set visible/invisible your listview.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. I think this is what I need. Sorry for the insolence, could you please give an example of the code. Thanks again!